# How to theme the register page (mysite.com/user/register)

Tags: theming

How to theme the register page (mysite.com/user/register). I'm using the Omega theme.

Where do I find the template page **user-register.tpl.php** ?

I don't need to add fields to the form, I just to theme this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To theme that path via a template file, you can use:

`page--user--register.tpl.php`

copy `page.tpl.php` to that filename, clear theme registry cache to apply.

Note, you may need to copy `page.tpl.php` from your base theme to your sub theme `/templates` folder to bring it into scope.